# format a region of text file with cc mode

Tags: region, formatting, cc-mode

I have a `textfile.txt` with content like the following

```
*decltype with two or more arguments
decltype does not take two arguments. Simply it can have an expression as its argument, and the comma operator is one way of creating expressions.
Example:

// begin c++ code
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>   // for std::false_type etc
#include <utility>       // for boolalpha modifier
// Non-templated helper struct:
struct _test_has_tostring {
template<class T>
static auto test(T* p) -> decltype(p->ToString()
,std::true_type());
template<class>
static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;
};
// end c++ mode

The end of the text file*
```

How can I reformat (pretty print) the c++ block only ?

Comment: Use `org-mode`?

Comment: If it were python code I can just simply M-x python-mode <RET> mark the region, then M-x indent-region <RET> then back to text-mode